# Android - How to implement parcelable for List<String> and List<Long>?

Tags: android

I need to send an object of this class to an activity; but I could not properly implement the reading and writing of weeks and weeklyPosts attributes.

I've tried to do with the answer to this question: [How to implement parcelable for List<Long>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774236/how-to-implement-parcelable-for-listlong)

and this: [Using an ArrayList<String> with a class that extends Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077342/using-an-arrayliststring-with-a-class-that-extends-parcelable),  but does not work.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Statistics implements Parcelable{

    private String forumName;
    private List<String> weeks = new ArrayList<String>();   
    private List<Long> weeklyPosts = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public Statistics(){

    }

    public Statistics (Parcel in){
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Statistics> CREATOR
    = new Parcelable.Creator<Statistics>() {
        public Statistics createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Statistics(in);
        }

        public Statistics[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Statistics[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(forumName);
                               //How to write the weeks List<String> ?
                               //How to write the weeklyPosts List<Long> ?
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        forumName = in.readString();
                               //How to read the weeks List<String> ?
                               //How to read the weeklyPosts List<Long> ?

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dest.writeList(weeks);` and  `dest.writeList(weeklyPosts);`

Comment: Why your constructor is not receiving List<Strong> and List<String> as attributes?

Comment: Complementing the response of @Blackbelt, i used:                 in.readList(weeks, String.class.getClassLoader());
in.readList(weeklyPosts, Long.class.getClassLoader());

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert your the Lists to arrays (Long[] and String[]), and then use

```
dest.writeLongArray(weeksArray); 
dest.writeStringArray(weeklyPostsArray); 

in.readLongArray();
in.readStringArray();
```

For the String list, you can also use:

```
dest.writeStringList(weeks);
```

and

```
 in.readStringList();
```